# Operation on pandas dataframe depending on type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

Is there any elegant way in a Pandas Dataframe with several columns of `float64` and other types to make a global operation only on the `float64` elements?

What I am looking for is to divide all `float64` elements by 100, without having to target or name specific columns.

Comment: Please mind showing sample data and your attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`df.select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html).

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns
df[cols] = df[cols] / 100.
```

This will divide all `float64` columns by 100.  Note that if you have mixed `object` columns with some `float64` cells, they won't be divided (your question wasn't totally clear about whether you wanted to act on columns or elements)

Comment: works perfectly. you assumed right that I had consistent data